# When was Sombra first playable?

Tags: overwatch

Sombra was announced at Blizcon but when was she first playable on the PTR ?

Comment: ...why does it matter since she's playable now?

Comment: @n_palum Because Moira was just announced at Blizzcon and it will likely follow the same pattern.

Comment: But that's speculating that it will, you don't know for sure. She could take longer to release for any number of reasons

Comment: Jeff said at Blizzcon that Moira and the new map would go live "early next year."

Comment: @Fluttershy I saw the keynote this morning, he didn't say anthing abour Moira, all he said about the map's "It's coming early next year, but will be playable on the PTR very very soon"

Comment: @n_palum It was pretty safe to assume it would follow the same pattern and it did, Moira is now playable on the PTR on the Monday after Blizzcon exactly the same as Sombra.

Comment: @ИвоНедев Just as an FYI Moira is up on PTR now

Answer (score 4, accepted):

While Sombra came to consoles and the main game on the 15th of November last year, she was playable on the PTR the Monday after Blizzcon, mentioned [here](https://youtu.be/Xww8ynBGeco?t=130).

Answer (score 4):

Acoording to [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sombra_(Overwatch)), Sombra was first announced on 11/4/16 and was made playable on 11/15/16.

Comment: That's when she went to the mainstream game. But given that yeah she probably went into the PTR, the first patchday after Blizcon.